# How to add domain to Cisco ACE sticky cookie value?

Tags: cisco, load-balancing, cookies, cisco-ace

My Cisco ACE, by default, sets the sticky cookie to *not* have a domain set. This has the effect of serving the sticky cookie under the domain of the host requested:

```
Set-Cookie:rl-sticky-key=R1514415839;path=/
```

I'd like to use my domain so that my subdomains may share cookies:

```
Set-Cookie:rl-sticky-key=R1514415839;path=/;domain=.example.com
```

How can I configure my ACE to do this?